# How can I order at more than one level in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression:

```
public IList<Objective> GetObjectives(int examId)
    {
        var objectives = _objectivesRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(o => o.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
            .Include(o => o.ObjectiveDetails)
            .ToList();
        return objectives;
    }

public partial class Objective
{
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

How can I modify this expression so the Objective is returned in order of `Number` and the ObjectiveDetails are returned in order of `Number`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use projection here e.g.

```
var objectives = _objectivesRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(o => o.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
        .Include(o => o.ObjectiveDetails)
        .Select(x => new Objective {
            ObjectiveId = x.Id,
            ExamId = x.ExamId,
            Number = x.Number,
            ObjectiveDetails = x.ObjectiveDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Number).ToList()
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Number)
        .ToList();
return objectives;
```

Comment: `objectivedetails` is an `ICollection`, so you would need a `tolist` or `toarray` after the inner `order by`

Comment: Is it really necessary to create a `new Objective`? It would break any references to the original `Objective`s which could be very bad depending on the situation...

Comment: @DavidS. while you're right, there is no better way to do this in a single query.

Comment: @nawfal I added a call to `ToList`, however, I am sure you could even just do a direct cast to `ICollection<T>` which would be better - however, I can't be 100% on that. @DavidS. unfortunately that's a consequence of the type of query the user is after. It looks like the OP is using CodeFirst so it should be ok in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
public IList<Objective> GetObjectives(int examId)
    {
        var objectives = _objectivesRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(o => o.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
            .Include(o => o.ObjectiveDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Number))
            .OrderBy(o => o.Number);
            .ToList();
        return objectives;
    }
```

Comment: Would `Include` allow you to do the sorting? If so, I'd say this is a nicer solution than mines. However, as far as I am aware it's used purely as a selection mechanism. I could be wrong as `Include` with the Lambda support is an extension method so may allow it.

Comment: @James It will have an effect on the output order, but not necessarily what you'd expect.  Explicit ordering is much safer and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you'll have to do the ordering of the nested objects separately from your main query.  I don't believe there is a way to make the `Include` statement retrieve elements in order.

```
public IList<Objective> GetObjectives(int examId)
{
    var objectives = _objectivesRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(o => o.ExamId == examId || examId == 0)
        .Include(o => o.ObjectiveDetails)
        .ToList();
    return objectives.OrderBy(o => o.Number)
        .Select(o => {
            var record = o;
            record.ObjectiveDetails = record.ObjectiveDetails.OrderBy(d => d.Number).ToList();
            return record;
        });
}
```